# Das Wort 'haben' fallen lassen?

Tags: grammatical-case, grammaticality, book, writing

Ich lese gerade das Buch 'Die Welt von Gestern' von Stefan Zweig, und ich hab gemerkt, dass es oft so ausschaut, als ob er das Wort 'haben' fallen lässt.

Zum Beispiel:

> Und wir brauchten nicht lange, um zu entdecken, daß alle jene
>   Autoritäten, denen wir bisher Vertrauen geschenkt, daß Schule, Familie
>   und die öffentliche Moral in diesem einen Punkt der Sexualität sich
>   merkwürdig unaufrichtig gebärdeten - und sogar mehr noch: daß sie auch
>   von uns in diesem Belange Heimlichkeit und Hinterhältigkeit
>   forderten.

In diesem Satz (und in vielen ähnlichen), würde ich denken dass das Wort 'haben' oder vielleicht 'hatten' nach 'geschenkt' gehört. Offensichtlich kann das nicht ein falscher Satz sein, also kann jemand mir erklären, wieso der Zweig das so machen kann?

Comment: An welcher Stelle des Satzes würdest du denn ein "haben" erwarten?

Comment: @Iris "dass das Wort 'haben' (...) nach 'geschenkt' gehört"?

Comment: Im Schwedischen kann man hier "haben" schon weglassen, aber der Satz wandelt sich dann in Kanzleisprache ( oder mekwürdigerweise auch Umgangssprache!) um. Ist das im Deutschen vielleicht auch eine Stilfrage, ob hier "haben" weggelassen werden kann?

Comment: @Beta "Kanzleisprache" ist gut. Da kommt dieses Konstrukt auch im Deutschen ursprünglich her.

Comment: @johnl Strenggenommen ist das kein Duplikat, weil es nicht nach "wann", sondern nach "warum" fragt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Das ist archaisches Deutsch und wird "afinite Konstruktion" genannt - sie wird in modernem Deutsch praktisch nicht mehr verwendet.

Die afinite Konstruktion tauchte zuerst im Amts- und Juristendeutsch des 16. Jahrhunderts auf und wurde von der Gebrauchssprache und Literatur mit der Zeit übernommen. In der Literatur überlebte dieses Konstrukt bis ins frühe 20. Jahrhundert, wie man an deinem Zweig-Zitat sieht. In Literatur nach 1945 taucht es praktisch nicht mehr auf.

Es gibt die Vermutung, dass die afinite Konstruktion von der Amtsstubensprache ursprünglich aus dem Lateinischen, das ähnliche Partizipkonstruktionen kennt, übernommen wurde.

Comment: ... und überdies neigt man in Amtsstuben in der Zeit vor Erfindung der elektronischen Textverarbeitung dazu, Sachen abzukürzen. Ggf. wird man hier auch an Abk. etc. denken. MfG.